# How to attach some "metadata" to Android Listview items?

Tags: android, listview, sqlite

```
class Venue {
  private int id;
  private String name;
}
```

I populate the ListView with something like

```
List<String> venueNames = data.getVenueNames();
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, venueNames));
```

So after the user selects a particular list item, I'd like to do a SQLite query with the venue id, but this information is lost when creating the venue names. How do you guys solve this?

EDIT: I should mention that it isn't guaranteed that venue name is unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
List<String> venueNames = data.getVenueNames();
```

Don't do that. You are the one "losing" the information. If you don't want to lose it, don't lose it.

The simplest thing is to create an `ArrayAdapter<Venue>`, and have `Venue`'s `toString()` return `name`. Then, calling `getItem()` on your `ArrayAdapter<Venue>` will return a `Venue`.